# Adding an extension function to an interface for currying

Tags: kotlin

I have an external interface with some function accepting a callback with a couple of parameters:

```kotlin
interface A {
    fun myFun(callback: (String, Int) -> Unit)
}
```

As one of the parameters is useless in my case and I want to use the implicit `it` parameter, I'm trying to add an extension function to skip the parameter:

```kotlin
fun A.myFun(callback: (String) -> Unit) = this.myFun { c, _ -> callback(c)}
```

The problem is that the compiler can't resolve such an extension function. See it on [the playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS41LjMxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gICAgXG4gICAgXG59XG5mdW4gY2hlY2soYSA6IEEpIHtcbiAgICBhLm15RnVuIHt9XG59XG5cbmludGVyZmFjZSBBIHtcbiAgICBmdW4gbXlGdW4oY2FsbGJhY2s6IChTdHJpbmcsIEludCkgLT4gVW5pdClcbn1cblxuZnVuIEEubXlGdW4oY2FsbGJhY2s6IChTdHJpbmcpIC0+IFVuaXQpID0gdGhpcy5teUZ1biB7IGMsIF8gLT4gY2FsbGJhY2soYyl9XG4ifQ==)

> Expected 2 parameters of types String, Int Type mismatch: inferred
> type is () -> Unit but (String, Int) -> Unit was expected

1. Is this the expected behavior?
2. Is there any other way to achieve the goal? I mean defining only one parameter and using an implicit it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the playground example you have is complaining because you are not providing the callback properly.

You have:

```
fun check(a : A) {
    a.myFun {}
}
```

Try one of these:

```
fun check(a : A) {
    a.myFun { s -> println(s) }
    a.myFun { s,i -> println("$s, $i") }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use implicit `it` in this case?

Comment: Not at the moment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18451